# Workmanager and android_alarm_manager_plus not working in background

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, background-process

Long Story Short, I'm working on a weather app as my first project of Flutter, for which I want to send periodic notifications to app user about weather updates, thrice a day. To do so I want to run a function that first fetches weather using API and then send local notification. I'm using `android_alarm_manager_plus` package to execute task in background.

Issue is Instead of sending notification on specified time, app send notification only when it is opened in foreground.

Here is the code I'm using, also all functions used are defined, all permissions are mentioned in manifest.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(0);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(1);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.cancel(2);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
    const Duration(days: 1),
    0,
    MorningAlarmTask,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
    startAt: calculateDurationFromSpecificTime(TimeOfDay(hour: 6, minute: 30)),
    exact: true,
    rescheduleOnReboot: true,
    wakeup: true,
  );

  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
    const Duration(days: 1),
    1,
    NoonAlarmTask,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
    startAt: calculateDurationFromSpecificTime(TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 30)),
    exact: true,
    rescheduleOnReboot: true,
    wakeup: true,
  );

  await AndroidAlarmManager..periodic(
    const Duration(days: 1),
    2,
    NightAlarmTask,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
    startAt:calculateDurationFromSpecificTime(TimeOfDay(hour: 21, minute: 00)),,
    exact: true,
    rescheduleOnReboot: true,
    wakeup: true,
  );

  String route = '';
  await userName.initPrefObj();
  if (userName.getName() == null) {
    route = "/first";
  } else {
    route = "/normal";
  }
  runApp(MainApp(firstRoute: route));
 }
```

I tried using Workamanager also but still same results.

Below are Logcat logs for the background task.

[image: App In Foreground]
When App Is In Foreground

[image: When App In Background]
When App is in background

How can be this be fixed ensuring that notifications are delivered at mentioned time only.